# How to start/stop gif with IntersectionObserver when in viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, intersection-observer

I tried to implement a code on my website with the intersection observer, where the first frame of a gif should show on the page until you scroll to a point where it is more or less in the middle. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't and when I did minor changes to optimize things suddenly it didn't work anymore and I can't find the mistake. I'm only somewhat familiar with Python, so JS is completely new to me, I'm sorry if it's a stupid syntax mistake or other basic stuff I should now but I really can't spot the problem.

I'd be really glad about help!

```
<img id="test" src="thumbnail.jpg" style="float: none; border-radius: 15px;" width="484" height="272">

<script>
  const config = {
  root: null, 
  rootMargin: '-100px',
  threshold: 0.5
};

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting){    
      entry.target.src = "active.gif";}
    else{
      entry.target.src = "thumbnail.jpg";}
  }, config)
})

observer.observe(document.getElementById("test"))
```